# Nginx&Apache2: If / is forgotten, apache redirects to its local port

Tags: apache, redirect, nginx

I have a Apache webserver setup behind a Nginx reverse proxy, handling SSL & subdomains.

It works fine for pretty much everything, except that if I forget the last / at the end of the url (e.g. `https://vps.com/url` don't have a / at the end), Apache redirects me to its local port (Apache is listening only to 127.0.0.1, port 4000, and if I forget the /, it redirects me to `https://vps.com:4000/url/` which obviously don't work).

This is my nginx config:

```
server {

    listen 443 ssl;

    // SSL Certificate location & such

    access_log /var/log/nginx/apache-ssl-access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/apache-ssl-error.log;

    server_name <my remote url>;

    location ~ {
            proxy_set_header                X-Real-IP               $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header                X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header                Host                    $host;
            proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:4000;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }
}
```

and this is the apache config file that is handling the service:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:4000>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    LogLevel warn ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

My server is setup on a Debian8 machine, running these versions:

- `Apache/2.4.10`
- `nginx/1.10.2`

I don't know what is redirecting or how I can prevent that, any idea ?

Comment: And the question is ?

Comment: Try replacing `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4000;` with `proxy_pass http://vps.artemix.xyz:4000/;` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Apache is issuing a 3xx response to append a trailing slash to a URI ending with a directory name.

An indirect solution would be to use the `proxy_redirect` directive in `nginx` to convert the redirect from an internal address to an external address.

Just changing your `location` block to a prefix location (see [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location)) and appending a `/` to your `proxy_pass` statement might work, as the default action may be enough to fix the problem:

```
location / {
    ...
    proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:4000/;
}
```

If a more specific solution is required, multiple `proxy_redirect` statements can be added to the `location` block.

To find the exact mapping you need, you should use `curl` (or suitable browser tools) to analyse the `Location` header in the HTTP 3xx response which sets the URL to an internal address.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect) for more.

Comment: I changed my `location ~` to `location /` and added the / at the end of the proxy-pass line (before the ;). When I try to access, it does the same, and the Location header is `http://vps.artemix.xyz:4000/class/` when trying to access `https://vps.artemix.xyz/class`.

Comment: Try adding: `proxy_redirect http://vps.artemix.xyz:4000/ https://vps.artemix.xyz/;` to the `location` block.

Comment: Added `proxy_redirect          http://vps.artemix.xyz:4000/ https://vps.artemix.xyz/;
                proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:4000/;` in the nginx location /. It still does it. (currently active)

Comment: And you restarted `nginx`?

Comment: yup, `systemctl restart nginx` each time

Comment: Use `nginx -T` to check your configuration file and make sure `nginx` is reading the correct file - otherwise, I cannot explain why your redirect directive is being ignored.

Comment: It's reading all the default config files (they do not contain anything that conflicts) and the config file given in ask topic. It seems to really ignore the redirection.